# Error C2893: Failed to specialize function template VC++ 2012

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Given this code I have a compiler error I've had trouble solving:

```
struct TestType
{
  void PrintX( void )
  {
    printf( "TestType::PrintX : %d\n", x );
  }

  int x;
};

// Error here, BuildFunction overload not found
Function f = BuildFunction<decltype( &TestType::PrintX ), &TestType::PrintX>( &TestType::PrintX );

// Here is the overload
template <typename FunctionType, FunctionType *FunctionPtr, typename C>
Function BuildFunction( void (C::*fn)( void ) )
{
  return Function( fn, &CallMethodVoid<FunctionType, FunctionPtr, C> );
}
```

My exact error message is:

```
1>main.cpp(141): error C2893: Failed to specialize function
  template 'Function BuildFunction(void (__thiscall C::* )(void))'
1>          With the following template arguments:
1>          'void (__thiscall TestType::* )(void)'
1>          'TestType'
```

This code works just fine with static C functions (and the appropriate overloads), I just have this issue when trying to deal with a class or struct method. Any ideas on what the problem may be?

Comment: Is the second parameter in template params of your BuildFunction method correct?

Comment: @Smac89 I'm pretty sure it is. It works with C functions. It might need to be something slightly different for methods though, which is why I have the question here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the type of the second template parameter of `BuildFunction<>`.

The first template parameter `FunctionType`, deduces to `void (TestType::*)(void)` since you've passed `decltype(&TestType::PrintX)` as the first template argument. The second template parameter as you specified it, reads `FunctionType *`. So the second template parameter is expecting a `void (TestType::**)(void)` (a pointer to a pointer to member function), which I don't think is what you intended. If you change the second template parameter to be `FunctionType` instead of `FunctionType *`, I think you'll get what you expect.

Comment: @RandyGaul Could you accept the answer if it was what you were looking for?

Comment: Whoops yeah sorry about that